# Expanding xticks in Matplotlib to show complete data in COLAB

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a plot on Matplotlib to see average salaries of developers based on the years they've spent coding and I get xticks as:

[image: Screenshot of the Plot]

In this Plot, You can see that the xticks are so merged between each other that we can't see the xticks properly. What are the ways to go about it to see the xticks properly?

```
degrees = 90

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.groupby('YearsCode').agg({'salarymonth' : 'mean'}))

ax.set_xlabel('Years in Numbers')
ax.set_ylabel('Salary per Month in Dollars')
ax.set_title("Salaries of Developers based on Years spent coding")
plt.xticks(rotation= degrees)


plt.show()
```

I'm using the code above and the dataset is The Stack Overflow Developers' Survey 2020

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,6))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, This worked now I have to change the rotation for Less than 1 year and More than 50 years to fit it. Means a lot!